# Exercise 6.3.N. on Ravi Vakil's notes (on morphism from $S$ scheme to $\mathbb{P}_B^n$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am working on Exercise 6.3.N. on Ravi Vakil's notes (on morphism from $S$ scheme to $\mathbb{P}_B^n$) and I would like some assistance. The exercise states: Let $B$ be a ring. If $X$ is a $B$-scheme, and $f_0, ..., f_n$ are $n+1$ functions on $X$ with no common zeros, then show that $[f_0, ..., f_n]$ gives a morphism of $B$-schemes $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_B^n$.

I would appreciate any hint, comments, etc. Thank you very much!

---

**Edit (Not by OP)** (10/06/2021). In the [2017 version](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) of the notes, this is exercise 6.3.M.

Comment: Now in the 2022 Aug version, it's exercise 7.3.O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I denote the homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbf{P}^n_B$ by $x_0, \dots, x_n$ then $X_{f_i}$ should map into the affine open $D(x_i) \subset \mathbf{P}^n_B$. To specify this restriction you just need to give a $B$-homomorphism $B[x_0/x_i, \dots, x_n/x_i] \to \Gamma(X_{f_i}, \mathscr{O}_X)$. What's the right formula? Then check that these agree on overlaps.

Comment: What does the notation $X_{f_i}$ mean here? Thank you!

Comment: @Oga The open set of points where $f_i$ does not vanish, in the sense that its image in the residue field is not zero. I'm sure he defines something like this at some point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I figured it is the map that sends $x_l/x_i to f_l |_{X_{f_i}}$. Could you possibly explain me why the morphisms $[f_0, ..., f_n]$ and  $[gf_0, ..., gf_n]$ to $\mathbb{P}_B^n$ are the same, if $g$ does not vanish anywhere on $X$? This is part b of the question. I can see that the map of topological spaces are the same, but they seem to have (a slightly) different maps of sheaves... Thank you!

Comment: @Oga I should have included more of an indication of what's going on. I think you want to send $x_l/x_i$ to $f_l/f_i$. This should make part (b) more obvious!

Comment: oops, I guess I had a wrong map! Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Is it possible to do question without gluing by any chance? I am curious because there is a remark after the exercise that says something like "we don't need tedious gluing arguments"

Comment: @Oga My guess is that he means "having done this exercise, you can specify some functions into $\mathbf{P}$ without gluing arguments". The general prescription is to cut things up into affines in order to do anything and that's a pain. The real improvement will come in section 16.4 but again, the proof there involves looking at the standard affine cover and gluing. But once that's done, you can work with an $(n+1)$-tuple of sections. Something to look forward to.

Comment: I see. Ok. That makes sense. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another solution. We have done most of the gluing work already in what is now (December 2022 version) exercise 7.3.F. There we construct a natural map $\mathbb{A}_B^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}_B^n$. (Technically we've only done it for fields $k$, but the construction of course works generally for rings $B$.) Hence it suffices to produce morphism $X \to \mathbb{A}_B^n \setminus \{0\}$, which also more or less directly solves subtask (b). But this is easily constructed: A morphism $\varphi: X \to \mathbb{A}_B^n$ is induced by the ring morphism
$$
\begin{align}
B[x_0,...,x_n] &\to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \\
x_i &\mapsto f_i
\end{align}
$$
and we are left to show that this morphism doesn't hit $0 \in \mathbb{A}_B^n$. Note that the pullback of the function $x_i \in \Gamma(\mathbb{A}_B^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_B^n})$ is $f_i \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Since we have a morphism of locally ringed spaces, $x_i$ vanishing at $p \in \mathbb{A}_B^n$ implies $f_i$ vanishes at all $q \in \varphi^{-1}(p) \subseteq X$. But at $0 \in \mathbb{A}_B^n$, all $x_i$ vanish. Thus all $f_i$ vanish at all $q \in \varphi^{-1}(0)$. By assumption such a point $q$ can't exist, showing that $\operatorname{im} \varphi \subseteq \mathbb{A}_B^n \setminus \{0\}$.